# Simplification Tolerance value field is missing from Simplify Polygon tool of ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, geoprocessing

Trying to run Simplify Polygon (Cartography -> Generalization) tool in ArcGIS 10.2 (ArcInfo License).

I ran the tool successfully once, then tried again on a new polygon, but the simplification tolerance value field is missing...so running the tool results in an error that the missing value is required.

I tried restarting ArcMap but the field is still missing.

Is this a bug in the software or has anyone else had a similar experience?

Comment: Are you sure the field type of the tolerance measurements is not type text and in fact exists in the other feature class?

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include a screenshot of the tool dialog with the values you entered for its parameters, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you installed IE11? There is a bug registered as  [NIM097058 - The 'Simplification Tolerance' option disappears from the Simplify Line and Simplify Polygon geoprocessing tools after installing Internet Explorer (IE) 11](http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/TklNMDk3MDU4). It's solved in 10.3. See bug description for workarounds in 10.2.

Comment: I uninstalled IE 11 and it appears to have fixed the issue.  Also, I was able to run the tool successfully through the python window as a temporary workaround.

Comment: Yes, and running the tool in batch mode is also an option, the parameter is then visible.